# Inverse powers of square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

### Approach

I have a square matrix $B$, and I am currently looking for $B^{-4}$. I am just wondering if it's possible to compute the inverse first, then raise it to the 4th power.

### Example/Solution

**Step 1.** Find $B^{-1}$

$B^{-1} = \frac{1}{det(B)}\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}$

**Step 2.** Find $B^{-1}$ to the fourth power $(B^{-1})^{4}$

$(B^{-1})^4 = (\frac{1}{det(B)}\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\
-c & a
\end{bmatrix})^4$

### Why

I know that in plain arithmetic $(x^a)^b = x^{a*b}$ just not sure if that also is the case in linear algebra. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try an experiment to test if $(B^{-1})^4 = B^{-4}=(B^4)^{-1}$? What did you get?

Comment: Hint: what is $(B^{-1})^4 B^4$?

Comment: @Somos I don't actually know what $B^{-4}$ is in order to test. I just started a chapter on determinants today, so this isn't actually a real example of a question for me to check the values against.  I've also learned the hard way picking my own random questions to test on sometimes things work for other reasons, and not because you're right in all instances.

Comment: @user619894 My expectation is it would be $B^{-1 * 4}$ but i'm not sure if that's true

Comment: Okay. What do you think $B^{-4}$ is supposed to be? What is the definition to use? If you don't know, consider that $B^{-4} := (B^4)^{-1}$ and verify that this is the same as $(B^{-1})^4$.

Comment: @Somos I would assume it's the inverse raised to the fourth power, but I'm not actually sure. I don't know if regular exponent laws hold for matrices the same way they do for regular numbers since operations are defined differently (in terms of operations you need to do) in linear algebra than they are in standard arithmetic.

Comment: Again, proceed as **if** "it's the inverse raised to the fourth power" and see what happens. If you don't try, you'll never know. Sure, matrix multiplication is not commutative **in general** but for powers of a single matrix it is just like regular numbers. Try it and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same than normal arithmetic simply because you can write:

$\begin{align}(B^{-1})^4B^4
&=B^{-1}B^{-1}B^{-1}\overbrace{B^{-1}B}^IBBB\\
&=B^{-1}B^{-1}\overbrace{B^{-1}B}^IBB\\
&=B^{-1}\overbrace{B^{-1}B}^IB\\
&=\overbrace{B^{-1}B}^I\\
&=I\end{align}$

Therefore $(B^{-1})^4$ is the (left, but you can do the same on the right) inverse of $B^4$, meaning that $(B^{-1})^4=(B^4)^{-1}$.

Remark that it does not tell us what $B^{-4}$ is, it is a convention that considering the calculation above works the same as for scalars, we decide that $B^{-4}$ is a practical notation for $(B^4)^{-1}$ (note: as we would do for any multiplicative group).